# install dual OS

Tags: linux-mint

I have installed Linux mint on my laptop and now i want to install another OS win 10 (want to keep both). When i installed Linux i made partitions as

[image]

I want to install win 10 on sda4. Previously when i tried to install win 10 it gave an error(cant install partition must be formatted using ntfs).

Comment: you can follow the steps in this [url](http://www.tecmint.com/install-linux-mint-18-alongside-windows-10-or-8-in-dual-boot-uefi-mode/)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/171428)

Comment: Thanks for answering! but the solution you mentioned was installing Linux on windows i want to install windows on Linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this by trying the mkntfs that will create a ntfs partition on the device that you indicate.Then in the case of your notebook...

Comment: can you please mention full command for my partition sda4, i am new and i don't know how to do that

Comment: mkfs.ntfs [device]  like this sample here ->   mkfs.ntfs  /dev/sda4 

 -like this. Ok!

...after this your ntfs partion are created, and you can format then!